# ML High-order function

Tags: function, sml

Write an ML High-order function philter(f,x,L) that takes a function f and an element x and returns the list of all those elements y on list L such that f(x,y) = true.

Philter:((a’ * a’)→bool * a’ * a’list)→a’list

My code

```
fun filter p [] = [] | filter p (x::xs) =
if p x
then
    x :: filter p xs
else
    filter p xs;

    filter (fn(x) => x<6) [6,3,0,1,8,5,9,3]; filter (fn(x) => x<6)
```

and i have diffrent val filter = fn : ('a -> bool) -> 'a list -> 'a list

any one can help me ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your function only takes a list and a function as argument where is the third argument e.g element `x` ??
As a consequence you check the condition `p x` and not `p(x,y)`, from your description `p` should have type:

```
(a'* a') -> bool
```

Here is my implementation:

```
fun filter (p :('a * 'a -> bool) , _ ,[]) = [] 
  | filter (p, x ,(y::ys))= if p (x,y) then y :: filter (p, x, ys)
                                   else filter (p, x, ys);
```

and here is a tail-recursive implementation:

```
fun filter2 (p : ('a * 'a -> bool), x, L)=
    let
        fun filter3 (p, _, [], L) = rev L 
          | filter3 (p, x, (y::ys), L) = if p (x,y) then filter3 (p, x, ys, (y::L))
                                                    else filter3 (p, x, ys, L);
     in
        filter3 (p, x, L, [])
      end
```

Example (see types and results):

```
val filter = fn : ('a * 'a -> bool) * 'a * 'a list -> 'a list

val filter2 = fn : ('a * 'a -> bool) * 'a * 'a list -> 'a list

val it = () : unit
- filter ((fn(x,y) => x<y), 4,[6,3,0,1,8,5,9,3]);
val it = [6,8,5,9] : int list

- filter2 ((fn(x,y) => x<y), 4,[6,3,0,1,8,5,9,3]);
val it = [6,8,5,9] : int list
```

Comment: this answer give me different val I would to have this val  ((a’ * a’)→bool * a’ * a’list)→a’list

Comment: first fun filter should have 3 parameters [ function f1 , num, list ] and f1 function have two parameters [ num ,and sent element element in the list ] to cheek any constant equation u add like

Comment: { n + element = 10 }  example: list [ 1,2,3,4] num = 2 in f1 (2,1){ if 2+1 = 10 then true  else false}  in this case return false and it will continue f1 (2,2){ if 2+2 = 10 then true  else false} return false

Comment: Glad to help !!

Answer (score 0):

By relying on the built-in `List.filter`, your `philter` could look like:

```
fun philter (f, x, L) = List.filter (fn y => f (x, y)) L
```